# Upload images on server

Tags: php, android

```
<?php
  $target_path1 = "uploads/";
  
  /* Add the original filename to our target path.
  Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */
  
  $target_path1 = $target_path1 . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path1)) 
  {
      echo "The first file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'])."has been uploaded.";
  } else {
      echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
      echo "filename: " .  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
      echo "target_path: " .$target_path1;
  }
?>
```

this have 3 error

> Notice: Undefined index: uploaded_file in D:\anddev\project\web\upload_test\upload_media_test.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined index: uploaded_file in D:\anddev\project\web\upload_test\upload_media_test.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined index: uploaded_file in D:\anddev\project\web\upload_test\upload_media_test.php on line 11

How do I fix this code ?

Comment: can you post your java code where you are trying to upload this file.

Comment: I second InnocentKiller's request. It looks as though you have an incorrectly named field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always add check to make sure you are actually getting something,

You can make use of [is_uploaded_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) Try it like this:

```
<?php
  if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']){
    //we got something, set it up
    $target_path1 = "uploads/";
    $file = basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);        
    $full_path = $target_path1.$file; 
    //perform the upload
  if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $full_path)) {
      echo "The first file ".$file." has been uploaded.";
    } else {
      echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
      echo "filename: " .  $file;
    }
  }else{
      echo "Nothing was uploaded";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

put:

```
<?php
var_dump($_FILES);
exit;
```

just on the beginning of a file and check what is there. You have wrong key in your array. Check what is the correct key of your input file.