# Uploading a picture to the server

Tags: php

I am trying to upload files to a server from my site, but this PHP code reports some errors when run:

```
<?php
      $target_path1 = "uploads/";

     /* Add the original filename to our target path.
     Result is "uploads/filename.extension" */

     $target_path1 = $target_path1 . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $target_path1)) 
      {
      echo "The first file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'])."has been uploaded.";
     } else {
       echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
       echo "filename: " .  basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
       echo "target_path: " .$target_path1;
    }
    ?>
```

The errors I got were

```
Notice: Undefined index: uploaded_file in D:\anddev\project\web\upload_test\upload_media_test.php on line 5

Notice: Undefined index: uploaded_file in D:\anddev\project\web\upload_test\upload_media_test.php on line 6

Notice: Undefined index: uploaded_file in D:\anddev\project\web\upload_test\upload_media_test.php on line 11
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Add your html form code please.

Comment: That means that `$_FILES['uploaded_file']` doesn't exist, post the HTML form as well, the error is probably in the file input name.

Comment: Is your `<input>` named `uploaded_file`?  Did you add `enctype='multipart/form-data'` to your form?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upload images on server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988893/upload-images-on-server). please dont post the same question twice it is not allowed here.